# Angular 2 material пропадают значения из инпутов в *ngFor

Tags: html, angular2, material-design, materialize-css

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of products.product.parameters">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input id="param_name" class="autocomplete" required min="1" type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="item.name">
            <label for="param_name">Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input id="param_value" required min="1" type="text" name="value" [(ngModel)]="item.value">
            <label for="param_value">Value</label>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Выше представлен кусок HTML, в котором выводятся все параметры, так же есть кнопка добавления нового параметра, он добавляется в массив `products.product.parameters`.
Все как-бы хорошо, старые значения из массива не исчезают, добавляются новые, на форме появляется новая полоска с 2-мя `<input>`, но(!) значения, содержащиеся во всех предыдущих `<input>` перестают отображаться, т.е. они просто выглядят, как пустые, хотя данные из массива никуда не исчезают.
Пробовал ниже через `<span>` выводить данные - все ок, исчезают именно из `<input>`.
Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно дать каждому элементу уникальный name

```
<div *ngFor="let item of products.product.parameters; let i = index">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="param_name" class="autocomplete" required min="1" 
        type="text" name="name-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.name">
     <label for="param_name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="param_value" required min="1" type="text" name="value-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.value">
    <label for="param_value">Value</label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Приложил рабочий код немного в ином стиле.

P.S. Если что непонятно - спрашивайте.

```js
angular.module('some', [])
.controller('someCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = {
    product: {
      parameters: [
        { name: 'its name', value: 'its value' },
        { name: 'its name 2', value: 'its value 2' }
      ]
    }
  };
  
  $scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.products.product.parameters.push({});
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="some" ng-controller="someCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in products.product.parameters">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="param_name" class="autocomplete" required min="1" type="text" name="name" ng-model="item.name">
        <label for="param_name">Name {{$index}}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="param_value" required min="1" type="text" name="value"  ng-model="item.value">
        <label for="param_value">Value {{$index}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="addRow()">Добавить строку</button>
  <br />
  <pre>{{products.product.parameters}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: в общем и целом у меня абсолютно аналогичное добавление, но у меня angular2, возможно это пока еще его косяк

Comment: а, это angular2? к сожалению, с его директивами не знаком.